# Google Sheets Query Function - Referencing Cell Value For Setting Limit & Offset Values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for some help which would be very much appreciated if possible. I've done my best to navigate the forums for the answer but don't appear to be clued up enough!I have attached my example workbook which gives the reference sheet (Exercise Library) and the sheet which I want to formulate more organised data (Formula Attempts). 
Aim 1: I would like a way of inputting a cell value for setting the limit (highlighted in A column A3 in orange) and also setting the offset (highlighted in B column B2 in blue)... I have tried this several ways after reading previous threads without success. I have tried with ',",&s and referencing 'Exercise Library'! ... Any ideas?
Aim 2: One other thing on the same formula can I wrap it to transpose this data to look like the purple area to the right?? within the same formula - I have tried Pivot and also transpose within the formula but get errors each time?

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18jzheac0zclL0l4NNwn6kYQkEQYtcNEepFe_Yi_5E88/edit?usp=sharing](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I have tried my best as above! Thanks

Comment: What are these `limit` and `offset` columns with values set for each row in Exercise Library tab? however in your trial formula you seem to be referring to just these 2 cells: A3 and B2? Hoping you could clarify on the core goal of this setup...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on the question, but if you want to use values in cells within your query, instead of this:

```
=QUERY('Exercise Library'!A2:K2000, "select A,B,C,D where K contains 'Knee' order by D limit INTA3 offset INTB2",0)
```

try this:

```
=QUERY('Exercise Library'!A2:K2000, "select A,B,C,D where K contains 'Knee' order by D limit "&int('Exercise Library'!A3)&" offset "&int('Exercise Library'!B2)&" ",0)
```

Basically, replace `INTA3` with `"&int('Exercise Library'!A3)&"`

This will fix limit and offset to a value in a targeted cell.

Comment: This is really really helpful - Really appreciate both your replies and help - works perfectly. Many thanks for taking the time. Chris